# My article state is not returning the proper data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I'm still getting the hang of react and react hooks. I'm working on this react challenge found here: [Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/react-paginated-articles/problem). My article state is not showing the proper data when the code first load. If you look in the console log my article state shows an empty array then the proper data but I need the proper data when my code first render otherwise my code won't execute right. It says I can't map over undefined. What's wrong with my code?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Articles = () => {
const [article, setArticle] = useState([])
const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/articles?page=${page}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setArticle(data))
 }, [page])
 const pgNums = Array(article.total_pages).fill().map((_, i) => i + 1)
 console.log(article)
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="pagination">
         {pgNums.map(n => <button data-testid="page-button" key={n} onClick={() => setPage(n)}>{n}</button>)}
        </div>
        <ul className="results">
    {/* {article.data.map(article => <li key="title-1" data-testid="result-row">{article.title}</li>)} */}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Articles;
```

Comment: It is undefined since your article is equal to `[]` before render (hence article.total_pages is undefined). You want to make pgNums as a state and set it on the useEffect callback so that it does the right thing (and render the button after you set the state of pgNums to whatever you have).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this when you try to access `article` it is not available. Because of `asynchronous api` call. What you can do either define another state `loading` which shows loader when data is fetching or `render`  nothing if data is not available.

In your case you can do like this:

```
if(!article) return null; <- It means data is not available do not show anything
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="pagination">
         {pgNums.map(n => <button data-testid="page-button" key={n} onClick={() => setPage(n)}>{n}</button>)}
        </div>
        <ul className="results">
    {/* {article.data.map(article => <li key="title-1" data-testid="result-row">{article.title}</li>)} */}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

each time page changes you are calling API, you should go with this conditional rendering. Instead of null you should return loading component/waitIndicator etc

```
const Articles = () => {
  const [article, setArticle] = useState([])
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const [pgNums, setPageNums] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/articles?page=${page}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.data);
        setArticle(data.data)
        setPageNums(Array(data.total_pages).fill().map((_, i) => i + 1))
      }

      )
  }, [page])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="pagination">
        {pgNums.length > 0 ? pgNums.map(n => <button data-testid="page-button" key={n} onClick={() => setPage(n)}>{n}</button>) : null}
      </div>
      <ul className="results">
        {article.length > 0 ? article.map((article,i) => <li key={i} data-tes.tid="result-row">{article.title}</li>) : null}
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```